# What's the best way to monitor your REST API?

Tags: api, http, statistics, monitoring

I've created an API based on the RESTful pattern and I was wondering what's the best way to monitor it? Can I somehow gather statistics on each request and how deep could I monitor the requests?

Also, could it be done by using open source software (maybe building my own monitoring service) or do I need to buy third party software?

If it could be achieved by using open source software where do I start?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Start with identifying the core needs that you think monitoring will solve. Try to answer the two questions "What do I want to know?" and "How do I want to act on that information?".

Examples of "What do I want to know?"

- Performance over time
- Largest API users
- Most commonly used API features
- Error occurrence in the API

Examples of "How do I want to act on that information?"

- Review a dashboard of known measurements
- Be alerted when something changes beyond expected bounds
- Trace execution that led to that state
- Review measurements for the entire lifetime of the system

If you can answer those questions, you can either find the right third party solution that captures the metrics that you're interested in, or inject monitoring probes into the right section of your API that will tell you what you need to do know. I noticed that you're primarily a [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) user, so it's likely that many of the metrics you want to know can be captured by adding before ( [Registering Before Filters On a Controller](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/41/registering-before-filters-on-a-controller)  ) and after ( [Registering an After Application Filter](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/54/registering-an-after-application-filter) ) filters with your application, to measure time for response and successful completion of response. This is where the answers to the first set of questions are most important ( "What do I want to know?" ), as it will guide where and what you measure in your app.

Once you know where you can capture the data, selecting the right tool becomes a matter of choosing between (roughly) two classes of monitoring applications: highly specialized monitoring apps that are tightly bound to the operation of your application, and generalized monitoring software that is more akin to a time series database.

There are no popular (to my knowledge) examples of the highly specialized case that are open source. Many commercial solutions do exist however: NewRelic, Ruxit, DynaTrace, etc. etc. etc. Their function could easily be described to be similar to a remote profiler, with many other functions besides. (Also, don't forget that a more traditional profiler may be useful for collecting some of the information you need - while it definitely will not supplant monitoring your application, there's a lot of valuable information that can be gleaned from profiling even before you go to production.)

On the general side of things, there are many more open source options that I'm personally aware of. The longest lived is Graphite (a great intro to which may be read here: [Measure Anything, Measure Everything](https://codeascraft.com/2011/02/15/measure-anything-measure-everything/)), which is in pretty common use amongst many. Graphite is by far from the only option however, and you can find many other options like Kibana and InfluxDB should you wish to host yourself.

Many of these open source options also have hosted options available from several providers. Additionally, you'll find that there are many entirely commercial options available in this camp (I'm founder of one, in fact :) - [Instrumental](https://instrumentalapp.com/) ).

Most of these commercial options exist because application owners have found it pretty onerous to run their own monitoring infrastructure on top of running their actual application; maintaining availability of yet another distributed system is not high on many ops personnel's wishlists. :)

Answer (score 30):

(I'm clearly biased for answering this since I co-founded [Runscope](https://www.runscope.com) which I believe is the leader in API Monitoring, so you can take this all with a grain of salt or trust my years of experience working with 1000s of customers specifically on this problem :)

I don't know of any OSS tools specific to REST(ful) API monitoring. General purpose OSS metrics monitoring tools (like Graphite) can definitely help keep tabs on pieces of your API stack, but don't have any API-specific features.

Commercial metrics monitoring tools (like Datadog) or Application Performance Monitoring (APM) tools like (New Relic or AppDynamics) have a few more features specific to API use cases, but none are centered on it. These are a useful part of what we call a "layered monitoring approach": start with high-level API monitoring, and use these other tools (exception trackers, APM, raw logs) to dive into issues when they arise.

So, what API-specific features should you be looking for in an API monitoring tool? We categorize them based on the three factors that you're generally monitoring for: uptime/availability, performance/speed and correctness/data validation.

#### Uptime Monitoring

At a base level you'll want to know if you're APIs are even available to the clients that need to reach them. For "public" (meaning, available on the public internet, not necessarily *publicized*...a mobile backend API is public but not necessarily publicized) APIs you'll want to simulate the clients that are calling them as much as possible. If you have a mobile app, it's likely the API needs to be available around the world. So at a bare minimum, your API monitoring tool should allow you to run tests from multiple locations. If your API can't be reached from a location, you'll want notifications via email, Slack, etc.

If your API is on a private network (corporate firewall, staging environment, local machine, etc.) you'll want to be able to "see" it as well. There are a variety of approaches for this (agents, VPNs, etc.) just make sure you use one your IT department signs off on.

Global distribution of testing agents is an expensive setup if you're self-hosting, building in-house or using an OSS tool. You need to make sure each remote location you set up (preferably outside your main cluster) is highly-available and fully-monitored as well. This can get expensive and time-consuming very quickly.

#### Performance Monitoring

Once you've verified your APIs are accessible, then you'll want to start measuring how fast they are performing to make sure they're not slowing down the apps that consume them. Raw response times is the bare minimum metric you should be tracking, but not always the most useful. Consider cases where multiple API calls are aggregated into a view for the user, or actions by the user generate dynamic or rarely called data that may not be present in a caching layer yet. These multi-step tasks or workflows are can be difficult to monitor with APM or metrics-based tools as they don't have the capabilities to understand the content of the API calls, only their existence.

Externally monitoring for speed is also important to get the most accurate representation of performance. If the monitoring agent sits inside your code or on the same server, it's unlikely it's taking into account all the factors that an actual client experiences when making a call. Things like DNS resolution, SSL negotiation, load balancing, caching, etc.

#### Correctness and Data Validation

What good is an API that's up and fast if it's returning the wrong data? This scenario is very common and is ultimately a far worse user experience. People understand "down"...they don't understand why an app is showing them the wrong data. A good API monitoring tool will allow you to do deep inspection of the message payloads going back and forth. JSON and XML parsing, complex assertions, schema validation, data extractions, dynamic variables, multi-step monitors and more are required to fully validate the data being sent back and forth is Correct.

It's also important to validate how clients authenticate with your API. Good API-specific monitoring tools will understand OAuth, mutual authentication with client certificates, token authentication, etc.

---

Hopefully this gives you a sense of why API monitoring is different from "traditional" metrics, APM and logging tools, and how they can all play together to get a complete picture of your application is performing.

Comment: We use RunScope heavily in our organisation and I must say, it is a 10/10 tool.

Comment: Hi John, how we can use RunScope in our company's internal applications which are not publically available?

Comment: https://www.runscope.com/docs/api-testing/agent

Answer (score 4):

I am using [runscope.com](https://runscope.com) for my company. If you want something free [apicombo.com](https://apicombo.com) also can do.
Basically you can create a test for your API endpoint to validate the payload, response time, status code, etc. Then you can schedule the test to run. They also provide some basic statistics.

Comment: apicombo.com seems to be down - at least when I tried now.

Comment: I'm using https://ihook.us, which also provides payload validation and status code validation functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried several applications and methods to do that, and the best (for my company and our related projects) is to log key=value pairs (atomic entries with all the information associated with this operation like IP source, operation result, elapsed time, etc... on specific log files for each node/server) and then monitorize with [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com). With your REST and json data maybe your aproach will be different, but it's also well supported.

It's pretty easy to install and setup. You can monitor (almost) real time data (responses times, operation results), send notifications on events and do some DWH (and many other things, there are lots of plugins).

It's not open source but you can try it for free if you use less than 50MB logs per day (that's how it worked some time ago, since now I'm on enterprise license I'm not 100% sure).

Here is a little tutorial explaining how to achieve what you are looking for: http://blogs.splunk.com/2013/06/18/getting-data-from-your-rest-apis-into-splunk/

Comment: Alright I will look into it and if I´m convinced I will give it a try. Thanks for giving me some insights on you situation. Are there more packages like Splunk available that make monitoring API´s a breeze?

Comment: Some time ago I looked for all available solutions and Splunk was the best for sure (best = my best = best cost, price, easy of use, easy of integration with already developed applications, etc...). What's exactly what you want to monitor?

Comment: Those would be my requirements to I think and if it's possible I'll add free of charge/open source as a requirement. I want to monitor all the requests  that have been made, what is the most popular endpoint, how long did it take to respond, where do they go to as our customers going to use it on their own applications. etc.