# how to include google analytics in php web service

Tags: php, web-services, google-analytics

I have a webservice writen in php and it is called from an desktop application installed on PC's.
I want to have a register of the users who calls the functions on the web service and for this **I only want to send hits to Google Analytics**.

webservice in php:

```
<?php
   require_once('lib/nusoap.php'); // basic include.. must go at the top

   $SERVICE_NAMESPACE = "urn:Service"; // create a namespace to run under.

   $server = new soap_server(); // the soap object from the include above.

   // this has many input parameters but we only need two: the service name and the namespace
   $server->configureWSDL('Service', $SERVICE_NAMESPACE);


    $server->register('test',// method name
        array('name' => 'xsd:string', 'name99' => 'xsd:string'),// input parameter called name.. and it's a string.
        array('return' => 'xsd:string'),// output - one string is returned called "return"
        $SERVICE_NAMESPACE,// namespace
        $SERVICE_NAMESPACE . '#hello1',// soapaction
        'rpc',// style.. remote procedure call
        'encoded',// use of the call
        'Nada interesante'// documentation for people who hook into your service.
    );

    function test($sName,$sName99) 
    {           
        return 'TEST ';
    }

    //This processes the request and returns a result.
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA); 
?>
```

I want to have google analytics info and for that i want to integrate the following script:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-89356985-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-89356985-1');
</script>
```

I don't know how to integrate in the test function. I want to know when the users calls the test function.

Thanks in advance very much.

Comment: paste that script in between your `<head> </head>`

Comment: I do not have <head> in my web service...

Comment: Can you give the full code of HTML, where do you call the function "test". The GTM-code must be placed as high as possible in <head>

Comment: are you creating apis or a web?

Comment: that is all the code i have

Comment: Google analytic is not for webservice monitoring.
why you need this in webservice ?

Comment: You need to formulate your question. What is your purpose. Are you using the API or do you just want to send hits to Google Analytics. And GA is for tracking interactions and events on website not server. You can use server-side tracking with Measurement Protocol. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

Comment: this might be help you 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760946/whats-the-best-way-to-monitor-your-rest-api

Comment: I have a webservice writen in php and it is called from an desktop application installed on PC's.
I want to have a register of the users who calls the functions on the web service.

Comment: I only want to send hits to Google Analytics, yes.

Comment: Then you have to use Google Measurement Protocol, i pasted link on comments. You can send pageviews and events with that to Google Analytics

Comment: I only want to simulate a hit on a website when the function is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the Javascript tracker unless your PHP script produces HTML and Javascript that is executed in a browser.

You can however use the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) to make server side calls to Google Analytics. That's basically an endpoint where you send predefined parameters with your custom values (via any method that can make http calls) and  they will register in Google Analytics.

Comment: any sample i can use, please?

Comment: @SomeOneMore I found a sample here: https://mizine.de/html/offline-conversion-tracking-in-adwords-ohne-upload-der-conversions/ -- let Chrome translate page to English and then read it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used as en example of what you need. use `http_build_query`to build you hit as you want to Google Analytics. Change `Google_Analytics_UA_String`to match your Google Analytics ID

```
<?php
    //some of the functions we need to make it work
    function generate_serial($n) {
        $c = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxz0123456789";
        $s = '';
        for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {
            $s .= substr($c,rand(0,37),1);
        }
        return $s;
    }
    function generate_uuid() {
        return generate_serial(8).'-'.generate_serial(4).'-4'.generate_serial(3).'-a'.generate_serial(3).'-'.generate_serial(12);
    }
    function ip() {
        $ip = false;
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ip = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
            $ip = trim(array_shift($ip));
        }
        elseif(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;
    }

    //define necessary variables
    define('Google_Analytics_UA_String','UA-XXXXXXXX-X');

    //create a UUID string for the user sending the request and store in the the session
    if(isset($_COOKIE['Google_Analytics_UUID']) and !empty($_COOKIE['Google_Analytics_UUID'])) {
        define('Google_Analytics_UUID',$_COOKIE['Google_Analytics_UUID']);
    }
    else {
        define('Google_Analytics_UUID',generate_uuid());
        setcookie('Google_Analytics_UUID',Google_Analytics_UUID,time()+63072000);
    }
    //compile the data we want to send to the API
    $data = http_build_query(array(
        'v'         =>  1,  // version
        'ds'            =>  'app',  // data source
        'tid'       =>  Google_Analytics_UA_String, // Tracking ID / Web Property ID
        'cid'       =>  Google_Analytics_UUID,  // Client ID
        'uip'       =>  ip(),   // IP Override
        't'         =>  'event',        // Hit type
        'ec'            =>  'site clicks',  // event category
        'ea'            =>  'click',        // event action
        'el'            =>  'button',   // event label
        'ev'            =>  'Click here!'   // event value
    ));

    //send using PHP's cURL extension
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //parse the response and send back to the browser
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($status == 200) {
        echo json_encode([
            'success'   =>  true
        ]);
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode([
            'error' =>  true
        ]);
    }
        ?>
```

Comment: i don't understand what you mean with "use http_build_query". Can you explain, please?

Comment: sorry, i don't know how to  use this.

Comment: Did you read the manual? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

Answer (score 0):

The exact running sample is:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXX-1&cid=35009a79-1a05-49d7-b876-2b884d0f825b&uid=myserid&uip=179.52.60.197&t=event&ec=Service&ea=SER&el=999999&z=54564653213',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Vanity-URL-Tracker',
    ));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

I have an example for [Page Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#page):

```php
public function send($trackingId, $host, $page, $title)
{
    $google_analytics_url = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect';
    $google_analytics_params = http_build_query(array(
        'v'   => 1,
        'tid' => $trackingId, // UA-xxxxxxx-x
        'cid' => uniqid(),
        't'   => 'pageview',
        'dh'  => $host,
        'dp'  => '/'.$page,
        'dt'  => urlencode($title),
    ));
    $url = $google_analytics_url.'?'.$google_analytics_params;

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Vanity-URL-Tracker',
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($status!= 200) {
        log_message('error', json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'response' => $resp)) );
    }
    if (curl_errno($curl)) {
        log_message('error', curl_error($curl));
    }
    curl_close($curl);

    return $resp;
}
```